# how to make a script be active for only on every hour on the half hour?

Tags: python, performance

I have a script and I want to code it so that it becomes active every hour on the half hour. This is the code I have so far.

```
from ConfigParser import *
import emailModule
from datetime import datetime
import time

configuration = ConfigParser()
configuration.read('Email.conf')

email = emailModule.emailModule(configuration)



while(True):


    if (datetime.now().minute > 28 and datetime.now().minute < 32):

        email.emailWeather()
        time.sleep(3000)
```

I am just wondering is there a better way of doing this in python? IE a more efficient way or more reliable way of doing things.

Comment: Not related to Python, but such things should be done using your operating system's job scheduler, e.g. the `cron`/`anacron` daemon or the Task Scheduler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using linux, or any other system with a cronlike daemon, you could ask the system to run your script every hour on the half hour by putting a line like this in your crontab: `30 * * * * /path/to/script`

Comment: thanks, the script has to run on windows though :S I could also use scheduled tasks is guess

Comment: I don't think you can schedule something for every hour with scheduled tasks though

Comment: @Richard the advantage of scheduled tasks is also that if your script crashes or gets killed, it will be started anew anyway in an hour. So you have a bit less worries about long-term stability.

Comment: http://drupal.org/node/31506 says you can. See step 3, under 'Configuring the task'.

Comment: @Richard http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569 and then scroll a bit to the Advanced part - you can apparently schedule hourly.

Comment: @extraneon Thanks I think that will do it and thanks to everyone else. My solution just didn't feel right and now it does :D

Answer (score 2):

You can use [cron jobs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron). Schedule it for every 1 hr. starting at 00:30:00.